# Не могу открыть ссылку в PHP

Tags: php, ссылки, telegram, link

Господа, доброго дня!

У меня есть ссылка поста в Телеграм:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot386180823:AAE2ITnRmCWRYRuT3cMGO7MZ7zE2hieGQW8/sendMessage?chat_id=@rech_append&parse_mode=Markdown&text=[%7F](https://rechtsanwalt-gmbh.ru/images/logo_uae.jpg)Dratuti_!
```

Но я никак не могу открыть ии из ПХП автоматом.

Ни так:

```
fopen( "https://api.telegram.org/bot386180823:AAE2ITnRmCWRYRuT3cMGO7MZ7zE2hieGQW8/sendMessage?chat_id=@rech_append&parse_mode=Markdown&text=[%7F](https://rechtsanwalt-gmbh.ru/images/logo_uae.jpg)Dratuti_!" );
```

Ни так:

```
header( "Location: https://api.telegram.org/bot386180823:AAE2ITnRmCWRYRuT3cMGO7MZ7zE2hieGQW8/sendMessage?chat_id=@rech_append&parse_mode=Markdown&text=[%7F](https://rechtsanwalt-gmbh.ru/images/logo_uae.jpg)Dratuti_!" );
```

Ни так:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot386180823:AAE2ITnRmCWRYRuT3cMGO7MZ7zE2hieGQW8/sendMessage?chat_id=@rech_append&parse_mode=Markdown&text=[%7F](https://rechtsanwalt-gmbh.ru/images/logo_uae.jpg)Dratuti_!');
echo $homepage;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема ? Всю голову сломал.

Comment: Сама ссылка прекрасно отрабатывает в Браузере!

Answer (score 1):

А ссылка точно верная, `https://api.telegram.org/bot386180823:AAE2ITnRmCWRYRuT3cMGO7MZ7zE2hieGQW8/sendMessage?chat_id=@rech_append&parse_mode=Markdown&text=[%7F](https://rechtsanwalt-gmbh.ru/images/logo_uae.jpg)Dratuti_!` Сервер ответ код ошибки 400 Bad Request. Если обрабатывать надо еще ошибки то лучше использовать `curl`.

А если изменить ссылку на `https://api.telegram.org/bot386180823:AAE2ITnRmCWRYRuT3cMGO7MZ7zE2hieGQW8/sendMessage?chat_id=@rech_append&parse_mode=Markdown&text=[%7F](https://rechtsanwalt-gmbh.ru/images/logo_uae.jpg` Я получаю статус `200`

Дока по `curl` http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.curl.php

Comment: Кстати .. спустя пару десятков проб file_get_contents() все-таки сработал .... НО вам все равно спасибо за реакцию !!